# Superslow loading of pages in Craft locally

Tags: performance, eager-loading, mamp

I am having trouble pinpointing the issue but I am struggling with some of my pages taking an absolute age to load. For example;

[image: Slow loading example] 
[image: Slow loading example] 
It might be a local MAMP issue, but some pages load fine and I would say these pages seem to load very slowly each time.

it could be related to the imager plugin (generating lots of images (srcset and sizes) but I expect this only to run in the first instance not each time. When I look in my folders (in dropbox) I can see the folders get updated by not each image file.

Or it could be my code and queries and setup, in particular Eager-loading.
I am struggling to get my head around this and I have so far been unable to reduce the amount of queries, this also varies on each load from between 107ish to 115ish.

Here is my code for this particular section. I do have related categories and images for each entry which I believe would benefit from Eager Loading, but I cannot establish if my code is correct for the eager loading?

```
<div class="container">
    {% set categories = craft.categories.group('cables') %}
    {% set cables = craft.entries({
            section: 'cables',
            with: [
                'cableCategory',
                'cableImage',
            ],
            order:  'title'
    }) %}

    {% for category in categories.relatedTo(cables) %}
    <div class="cableGroup">
        <h2 class="panel__title">{{ category }}</h2>
        <div class="cableGroup__description content // margin-bottomX2">
            {{ category.description }}
        </div>

        <ul>
            {% for cable in cables.relatedTo(category) %}
            {% set image = cable.cableImage[0] ?? null %}
            <li class="cable">
                <a href="#{{ cable.title|camel|upper }}" data-title="{{ cable.title }} &#xa;">
                    {% if image|length %}
                    {{ img.imagerSrcsetSizes(image, cable.title, '', 'thumb') }}
                    {% else %}
                        <img src="/assets/img/fallback-cable-thumb.jpg" alt="No Image Available">
                    {% endif %}
                    <h3 class="cable__tag">{{ cable.title }}</h3>
                </a>
            </li>

            {% endfor %}
        </ul>

        {% for cable in cables.relatedTo(category) %}
            {% include '_includes/cables/cableModal' %}
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Comment: You need to figure out if the time is being eaten by database queries (number and type) or code/PHP or a combination of both.  With devMode enabled, the SQL profiling output in the browser's console is sorted by slowest performing queries at the top.  Code profile output in `craft/storage/runtime/logs` is timestamped, so you can see where the big gaps are as the code is executing.

Comment: What do you mean by `When I look in my folders (in dropbox) I can see the folders get updated by not each image file.`? If you have the Imager config setting `cacheEnabled` = `false`, the images would be generated on every page load. My favourite way of debugging stuff like this is to just delete chunks of the templating code until I figure out what chunk takes the most time. ;)

Comment: @AndréElvan cacheEnabled is on by default I believe. When I say updating. I see the green icon turn to the blue updating icon in Dropbox (but this only happens for the folders and not the image files).